# Deriving Cyclomatic Complexity in .NET

Tags: .net, visual-studio, cyclomatic-complexity

I know that I can access the cyclomatic complexity to my code in Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer by right clicking and selecting "Calculate Code Metrics". I would like to expose this data for a web application to display it. Does anybody know of any way of accessing this data through an API?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I use [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) for stuff like that. You can create CQL queries in NDepend and execute them.
Example:

```
SELECT METHODS  WHERE CC > 8
```

returns the methods with a cyclomatic complexity greater than 8.

Answer (score 2):

As described in this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052269/free-c-metrics-calculation-library-dll/4005106#4005106)**, one can leverage the API of the **Gendarme** open source tool to calculate the cyclomatic complexity of a method

```
ModuleDefinition module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(fullPathToTheAssembly);

foreach (var type in module.Types)
{
    foreach (var me in type.Methods)
    {
        if (!me.HasBody || me.IsGeneratedCode() || me.IsCompilerControlled)
            continue;
        var r = AvoidComplexMethodsRule.GetCyclomaticComplexity(me);

        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", me.ToString(), r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no API. But you can read an XML file generated by the [Code Metrics Power Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=edd1dfb0-b9fe-4e90-b6a6-5ed6f6f6e615). So you would generate the code metrics XML file by command line like:

```
metrics /f:MyAssembly.dll /o:MetricsResults.xml
```

Then grab the data you want out of MetricsResults.xml.

More info on the power tool [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/camerons/archive/2011/01/28/code-metrics-from-the-command-line.aspx).

If you want to run code metrics in your TFS build, see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slange/archive/2011/04/14/running-code-metrics-as-part-of-a-tfs-2010-build-the-poor-man-s-way.aspx) and [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2011/01/30/integrating-code-metrics-in-tfs-2010-build.aspx) for options.

Answer (score -1):

I don't -- does Visual Studio have *any* APIs of that sort? -- but computing cyclomatic complexity is reasonably easy.  [Gendarme](http://mono-project.com/Gendarme) might be your answer.