# Visual Studio Code Metrics Results: call it programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, metrics, vspackage

For my master thesis, I'm writing a VSPackage (for VS 2013) to identify the critical methods in a project and I would like to include, in the algorithm used to classify the methods, also some of the metrics provided by Visual Studio.

In a VSpackage, is there a way to programmatically call the calculation of metrics (the one already embedded in Visual Studio.) and access, in a programmatic way, the results?

Comment: There probably is, but should you not be able to find it, consider calling the commandline equivalent and parsing the resulting XML. My endeavors into that bit of API bumped into so many internal sealed classes you can't access that I just bypassed it completely. Commandline tool lives here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41647

Answer (score 0):

You may not have that feature.
But, there are many sophisticated open-souces to implement code analysis jobs integrated with VisualStudio.

- many alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4005106/361100
- Brief introduction to NDepend: http://blog.octo.com/en/static-analysis-tooling-for-net-ndepend-in-depth/

Comment: Unfortunately NDepend is not a viable solution because of the price. My school does not have a licence for such library.

Comment: @Lando Why don't you check out alternatives that I suggest?

Comment: Sure, I will check out yours alternatives, as well as the solution proposed by jessehouwing. I was just pointing out that I will not try NDepend since I already know that I will not be able to use it, since it's not free.